# Android studio 2.2 EditText Border

Tags: android-edittext, android-studio-2.2

I upgraded Android Studio 2.2 preview 3 recently but the EditText style changed， In preView:
[image]

But run on my phone, It like this:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hyh.newlearn.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_show"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:hint="Hello World"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Why?  How to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

If I use classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3', it will show the error view.

If I use classpath 'classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'', it will show the right view.

Answer (score 0):

I have exaclty the same problem.

Yuhao,  here is my question

[android edittext on sdk version from 16-19 shown incorrectly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175008/android-edittext-on-sdk-version-from-16-19-shown-incorrectly)

but i thought it was couse of api.

You were right. 
We have to use last stable version
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'